# Laravel morphedByMany Query Returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this model

```
class Permission extends Model
{

      public function details(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Details', 'model', 'model_has_permissions', 'permission_id', 'model_id');

    }
}

class Details extends Model
{

   public function permission()
    {

    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Permission','model','model_has_permissions','model_id','permission_id');
    }
}
```

I'm execute this query

```
Details::with('permission')->find(55);
```

and got empty array

why happen this?and what is the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `permission()` method

change this

```
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Permission','model','.model_has_permissions','model_id','permission_id');
```

to this

```
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Permission','model','model_has_permissions','model_id','permission_id');
```

Comment: excuse me ,this is my typo was wrong here and in the orginal code this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to chain `find` after `with`. Here are your options.

1. Lazy Loading.

   ```
   Details::find(55)->load('permissions');
   ```
2. Eager loading with `where` clause

   ```
   Details::with('permissions')->where('id', 55)->get();
   ```

**UPDATE**

Shouldn't this be `morphToMany`?

```
public function details(): MorphToMany
{    
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Details', 'model', 'model_has_permissions', 'permission_id', 'model_id');
}
```

Or this?

```
public function permission()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Permission','model','model_has_permissions','model_id','permission_id');
}
```

Comment: hi,i think problem in relation not query,
i execute your queries and still got null array

Comment: is that possible run query from child in Polymorphic Relations or in Polymorphic Relations just execute query from parent?

Comment: hi, `MorphToMany` is the main relation, `MorphedByMany` is the **inverse** of the relation. It can be executed from both sides.